# Make error div .fadeOut when user select a "proper" value

Tags: jquery

I am almost done with a mockup and I need a little trick over this:

```
<form>
    <div class="line">
        <label>Embarque:</label>
        <select>
        <option value="first">Selecione a Estação</option>
            <option value="second" >Trianon-Masp | Linha 2 - Verde</option>
        </select>
        <div class="error">Selecione a estação de embarque</div>
    </div><!-- end line -->
</form>
```

When the user select the second option, the .error will fadeOut(); anyone got any idea how to roll about it?

Comment: lol, twice a -1 vote, nobody dares explaining it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an `id` for the `<select>` tag.

```
<select id="lineSelect">
```

Use this:

```
$("select#lineSelect").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "correct")
        $(".error").fadeOut();
});
```

Or, you can use:

```
$(".line select").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "correct")
        $(".error").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: keep in mind that it will bind onchange event to ALL select boxes on the page and hide all errors on the page if any of them is changed! also, there is no value 'correct'

Comment: I know. Will update the answer with the HTML too. :) Thanks @ZathrusWriter

Comment: The .change() was the ring thing to roll on, worked like a charm, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
$('div.line select').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == this.options[1].value) {
        $(this).next('div.error').hide('slow');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ENWw/)

Comment: Worked wonderfully too, but the .change seems to flow a bit easier. Thanks pal!